# How can I download django-1.2 and use it across multiple sites when the system default is 1.1?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, debian-lenny, virtualenv

I'm on Debian Lenny and the latest backports django is `1.1.1 final`. I don't want to use `sid` so I probably have to download django.

I have my sites located at: `/www/` and I plan on using mod_wsgi with Apache2 as a reverse proxy from nginx.

Now that I downloaded `pip` and `virtualenv` through pip, can someone explain how I could get my `/www/` sites which are yet to be made to all use `django-1.2`?

**Question 1.1**: *Where* do you suggest I download `django-1.2`? I know you can store it *anywhere* but where would you store it?

**Question 1.2**: After installing it how do you actually tie that `django-1.2` instead of the system default django 1.2 to the reverse proxied Apache conf?

**I would prefer it if answers were more specific than vague and have examples of setups.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up following the excellent guide @ http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/

I really like comprehensive tutorials like this, instead of some RTFM link to these types of things which do NOT cover integration of different services.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you consult:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

for how to setup mod_wsgi with virtual environments.

That way you can leave any existing Django alone and install new one into virtualenv and have your WSGI application under mod_wsgi use it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the Django package provided by Debian and install from the tar.gz download or use svn to get the latest.

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/install/#installing-official-release

Comment: Is that the preferred way of doing it, though? And how would you handle the situation if you wanted your existing sites to use `1.1.1` but multiple, newer sites using `1.2`?

Comment: I believe Graham Dumpleton's answer covers all that.